# Android not finding .SO library, although the file exists

Tags: android, shared-libraries

I'm using an external .SO library with my Android app. I've put the libs in `jniLibs/x86_64` and I'm using a X86_64 emulator.

When launching the app, I have an exception

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: be.henallux.myapplication, PID: 13404
    java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: library "libopenalpr.so.2" not found
        at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:1016)
        at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1657)
        at be.henallux.myapplication.ALPRJniWrapper.<clinit>(ALPRJniWrapper.java:9)
        at be.henallux.myapplication.OpenALPR$Factory.create(OpenALPR.java:80)
        at be.henallux.myapplication.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:29)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6975)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1213)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2770)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

Although, my libs are there, and the mentioned file exists

```
 Répertoire de D:\wrkfldr\MyApplication\app\src\main\jniLibs\x86_64

16-09-19  15:54    <DIR>          .
16-09-19  15:54    <DIR>          ..
16-09-19  15:39         3.267.088 libopenalpr.so.2
16-09-19  15:39         7.278.060 libopenalpr-static.a
16-09-19  15:39         3.267.088 libopenalpr.so
16-09-19  15:39           108.616 libopenalprjni.so.2
16-09-19  15:39           108.616 libopenalprjni.so
               5 fichier(s)       14.029.468 octets
               2 Rép(s)  421.288.173.568 octets libres
```

I feel there's something with the fact that there are two dots in the filename. But I can't find a fix. I've tried renaming `libopenalpr.so.2` to `libopenalpr_so.2, libopenalpr-so.2, libopenalpr.so_2` but none of them worked.

Why isn't Android able to find my library ?

Comment: Provide the full path in System.load("D:\wrkfldr\MyApplication\app\src\main\jniLibs\x86_64\libopenalpr.so_2") and see if it works.

Comment: As per [the Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#loadLibrary-java.lang.String-), System.loadLibrary must not contain any platform specific prefix, *file extension or path*. Plus, the Android App runs on a device that doesn't have this path.

Comment: You are right.I am just saying for test purpose.Recently I have some similar kind of issue.

Comment: Also are you mentioning the path in file tree implementation in build.gradle?

Comment: Normally you don't need to, adding the libraries to `jniLibs` does the trick. If I remove everything in this folder, the error says no libraries were found. When I add the libs in this folder, the error says it has found `libopenalpr.so` but not `libopenalpr.so.2`, so it can see some of them